# Mixing floating and absolute positioning issues

Tags: css, css-float, css-position, absolute

I'm trying to float three elements, no problem there. However in the two outside boxes I need to position an element vertically in the center, so I thought I would wrap them both in another div, float the wrapping divs and then absolute position the elements inside them and set the wrapping elements to `position: relative;` so it wouldn't mess with the layout and the three elements would stay floated correctly.

However it doesn't seem to have happened that way, the middle element still seems to get shoved all the way to the left.

My CSS:

```
.line_wrap {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 366px;
    min-width: 366px;
    max-width: 366px;    
}

.line_wrap .line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 366px;
    min-width: 366px;
    max-width: 366px;
    border-top: 1px solid #d9dce6;
}

.title {
    float: left;
}

.title h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 37px;
    color: #425080;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="fee_header">
    <div class="line_wrap">
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        <h2>Standard Fees</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="line_wrap">
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="contentClear"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MN88R/

I'm trying to position the two elements on the sides so that the border of them ends up in the vertical center of the text in the middle.

Comment: Can you add an image of your desired behavior?

Comment: Yes your question is a bit confused I think :)

Comment: @Oriol I thought of that but thought using a non-image solution would be better.

Comment: @Kursion I think I explained myself pretty well, care to expand on your comment!?

Comment: @Brett Of course, it's better to post the code than only an image. But adding a complementary image to make things clear doesn't hurt :). For example, I don't understand very well that, if you want *to position the two elements (...) in the vertical center of the text*, why do you need two elements? There is only one center, so they will overlap...

Comment: @Oriol Sorry, I misunderstood you. I thought you meant why not use an image to draw the line instead of using the border of the element. I have now done this and I have things working ok now. This question was just to find out why things weren't behaving the way they should (or the way I thought they should).

Comment: @Brett No problem, but could you add an image of the way you thought they should behave?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve correctly, then I think you may be just approaching it from the wrong angle and perhaps should try something other than using the 3 floating boxes.

If your goal is to have the title center to it's parent container, and the border then run across the vertical center of the heading text, I would try something more like this:

CSS

```
.title {
    height:20px;
    overflow:visible;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d9dce6;
    margin-bottom:20px;

}

.title h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 37px;
    color: #425080;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
       <div class="fee_header">
           <div class="title">
               <h2>Standard Fees</h2>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Here is a link to a new fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2KDQ4/1/

Just make sure that the font-size of your heading and the container div height are in the proportions that meet your needs. And the bottom-margin on title is set with what ever spacing you need.

Comment: You may want to add some `margin-bottom` to `.title` in order to avoid overlapping the title with following contents.

Comment: Great catch! Thanks, I edited the answer to include it.